# What directory does C++ look into when using the function GetFileAttributesA(Windows)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-c++

I have a directory A which has a file `someFile.ext`, I cd to directory A in my terminal. In directory B I have a tmp.exe, I run the `tmp.exe` from directory A. Now in the code of `tmp.exe` I have a function which checks if file `someFile.ext` exists or not using the function `GetFileAttributesA` (the file exists if this does not return `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`). Now I want to know when I call the function `GetFileAttributesA("someFile.ext")` in which directory does it look, in directory A or directory B? Mind you I am not providing full path just the fileName. Does this change behaviour change for 32bit and 64 bit architecture in Visual Studios.

Comment: It looks in whatever the calling process's current working directory is. Use [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) to see what directory that actually is. But based on your description, that is likely to be directory `A` since that was the CWD of the terminal where `tmp.exe` was run from. And no, this behavior does not change between 32bit vs 64bit.

Comment: It's going to look in the current working directory.  You can call the [`GetCurrentDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) function in kernel32 to be 100% sure.

Comment: C++ doesn't say anything about what that function does. Microsoft's documentation ought to tell you.

Comment: You can use a fully qualified path.  `GetFileAttributesA("C:\\Projects\\SomeFile\\someFile.txt");`

Comment: Using a relative path is not a solution to *any* problem. Now, what problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that, when given a relative path, all of the Windows file APIs are relative to the current directory for the process.

When you run a program, that program (initially) inherits the current directory from the parent process.  A process can change its current directory.

The above should be enough to answer your question.

---

But Windows is actually a bit more complicated than many realize, since a process actually has a current *drive* and one current directory *per drive*.  So the "current working directory" for a process is its current directory for the current drive.

- `C:\foo\a.txt` is an absolute path to a specific file.
- `foo\a.txt` is relative path, relative to the "current working directory" (that is, the current directory for the current drive) of the process.
- `D:a.txt` is also a relative path, but it's relative to the process's current directory for the `D` drive, even if the process's current drive is not `D`.
- `\foo\a.txt` might look like an absolute path because the process's current directory isn't relevant, but it's actually a relative path because it's relative to the root of the process's current *drive*.

The directory-per-drive wrinkle doesn't fit into the model of a lot of file system abstractions, especially in code ported from Posix platforms.

There are even more exotic filesystems out there, like VMS/RMS, which has a "default file specification" rather than a "current working directory".  Lots of people consider them two sides of the same coin, but they're conceptually very different beasts.

---

**Update:**  Commenters have pointed to one of Raymond Chen's blog posts that talks about how CMD.EXE creates the illusion of a current directory per drive.  It's true that CMD sets up the illusion to track the various current directories using special environment variables.  It's also true that Win32's [GetCurrentDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getcurrentdirectory) keeps track of just one current directory.

**However**, the rest of the Win32 file APIs respect and use those special environment variables set by CMD to resolve non-absolute paths, so even at the Win32 API level, if your process inherited the magic environment variables from CMD, the results are as if you had a separate current directory per drive.

Allow me to illustrate.  We'll start with a program that uses [GetFileAttributesW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfileattributesw) to determine whether the file `"D:a.txt"` exists.  I've hardcoded the file name to ensure we use exactly that string.  In other OSes, the shell often resolves file specifications in the command line before passing the arguments onto the program.

```
C:\Users\Adrian McCarthy\source>type test.cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    const WCHAR *file_path = L"D:a.txt";
    const auto attr = ::GetFileAttributesW(file_path);
    std::wcout << L'"' << file_path << L"\" was "
               << ((attr == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES) ? L"not " : L"")
               << L"found." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

C:\Users\Adrian McCarthy\source>cl /nologo /EHsc /W4 /WX test.cpp
test.cpp
```

If I set the current directory to the root of the `D` drive (where there is no `a.txt`) and then switch back to the `C` drive to run the program, we confirm that there is no such file.

```
C:\Users\Adrian McCarthy\source>d:

D:\>c:

C:\Users\Adrian McCarthy\source>test
"D:a.txt" was not found.
```

But if I change the current directory for drive `D` to `\foo`, where I do have an `a.txt`, then the same command finds the file, even though the program has no knowledge of the `foo` directory, not hardcoded in, and not from the "official" current working directory.

```
C:\Users\Adrian McCarthy\source>d:

D:\>cd foo

D:\foo>dir
 Volume in drive D is Data
 Volume Serial Number is D631-E371

 Directory of D:\foo

07/21/2021  09:49 AM    <DIR>          .
07/21/2021  09:49 AM    <DIR>          ..
07/21/2021  09:49 AM                24 a.txt
               1 File(s)             24 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  1,491,949,572,096 bytes free

D:\foo>c:

C:\Users\Adrian McCarthy\source>test
"D:a.txt" was found.
```

The only way this could work is because Win32 file APIs respects the magic environment settings the CMD set up and the test process inherited.

This matters because many "portable" projects use a file system abstraction layer that tries to explicitly resolve relative paths instead of letting the underlying system APIs to it.

If they decide `D:a.txt` is an absolute path and leave it alone on its way to the WinAPI, it'll work.  But if they consider `D:a.txt` to be a relative path, then they're going to ask the system for the current working directory and try to merge it with the relative path and either come up with something ill-formed or with an absolute path that doesn't exist.

Comment: Isn't the directory per drive thing something that cmd.exe implements rather than Windows itself? https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20101011-00/?p=12563

Comment: *"There isn’t actually such a concept as a* per-drive current directory *in Win32. In Win32, all you have is* a *current directory. The appearance that each drive has its own current directory is a fake-out by `cmd.exe` \[...\]"*.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  CMD plays a role, but Win32 plays along, which effectively gives you a directory per drive for the purposes of resolving relative paths even though the system tracks just one "current working directory" for your process.  I've edited my answer with a detailed explanation and demonstration.

Comment: @IInspectable:  I think that Raymond Chen quote can be a bit misleading in this context.  His point is that GetCurrentDirectory and SetCurrentDirectory track only one directory for the process, which is true.  But other Win32 filesystem APIs will resolve relative paths by using the per-drive current directories when appropriate.  I demonstrated that in my edit, but it's even documented (obtusely) in the remarks for GetFullPathName, which says, "If you specify 'U:', the path returned is **the current directory on the U: drive**."